# LinkedIn: Exchange JSAPI token to REST's OAuth token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, token, linkedin-api, jwt

**I'm working on a website which has the api (Ruby on Rails) and the client (Angular JS) on separated servers.**

As of that, I authenticate the user on the client with LinkedIn, I post the received data to the API's authentication method and I get JWT back from it.

Then I authenticate with the token attached to every request, while making all the LinkedIn API requests on the backend.

I see there were a lot of posts about *how to exchange jsapi token to oauth token*, but they have all been removed from LinkedIn's page and there are no usable information in the stored data.

---

***Note:*** all other StackOverflow answers are linking to those pages too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation was relocated to https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Gonna implement it asap. :)